# Dynamically load component as per user role Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to load specific components as per the user role in my Vue router.js.

Roles are handled through [websanova vue auth](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth) and the easiest way to check if a user has a role is by doing `Vue.auth.check('rolename')`

In my route file, I've tried with something like this:

```js
{
   name: 'profile',
   path: '/profile',
   component: () => Vue.auth.check('secretary')
      ? import('@/components/secretaries/LayoutProfile')
      : import('@/components/doctors/LayoutProfile'),
   props: (route) => ({
      editMode: false
   }),
   meta: {
      auth: true
   }
},
```

It seems to work for the first time: once the secretary logs in the `secretaries/LayoutProfile` component is mounted as expected.

But the issue comes if I log out as a secretary and log in as a doctor: the `secretaries/LayoutProfile` is still being used instead of `doctors/LayoutProfile`. **The only way to fix it is by refreshing the page.**

I'm not pretty sure how to deal with this, so far I can just imagine that `router.js` is loaded on my App `mount` lifecycle hook, therefore and despite log-in/log-out the router keeps the secretary component mounted.

I just want to be sure that this is not possible before thinking of another approach such as dynamically loading `children` components within a parent `Profile` component as per user roles.

FYI, I'm facing no errors at all, just wrong components mounted

Comment: From what I read what happens here is that router calls that `component` function only once, expecting Promise. Once that Promise resolves (component is loaded) it just stores the result and use it in the future ...which makes sense. Take a look for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59360512/381282) for some alternative solutions

Comment: btw what version of Vue (and Router) are you using?